# FeathersJs LEFT join another table (MongoDb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, feathersjs

I have a model for a service listings like

```
  price: { type: Number, required: true, min: 0, default: 0 },
  itemId: {
    type: mongooseClient.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'items',
    required: true,
  },
```

and with the after all hook I am doing a fastResolve with

```
joins: {
items: () => async (instance, context) => {
    if (instance && instance.itemId) {
      const item = await context.app
        .service('items')
        .get(instance.itemId);

      instance.item = item;
    }
    return context;

},
```

so in the end when I do a find for listings, I get the item object.
And while I can easily query for fields like price (listings?price%5B%24lt%5D=5000)

How should I query for inner fields of item, like weight? (when doing a listings find)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly pass a `$populate` query on the front end.

for eg: `?$populate=itemId`, here "itemId" is the data model's key which is referred to items model.

If you want to populate in the backend, you can create a custom hook for that.

```js
// src/hooks/setDefaultQuery.js

const setDefaultQuery = (fieldName, defaultValue) => (context) => {
  const { params } = context;
  const { query } = params;

  if (typeof query[fieldName] === 'undefined') context.params.query[fieldName] = defaultValue;
  return context;
};

module.exports = setDefaultQuery;
```

on hooks, you can use the `setDefaultQuery` like this

```js
{
  before: {
    all: [authenticate('jwt')],
    find: [setDefaultQuery('$populate', "itemId")],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: [],
  },
}
```

For more about the querying please check the link bellow
https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/querying.html

Comment: Thanks Santanu! While this populate option has significantly increased the performance of the query, I am still unable to query for nested values of which it populates stuff, additionally do you know, How can I populate within populate? eg. I populate by itemId, it grabs me that item, but that item also has userId and a modelId which I want to also resolve

Comment: So the structure is like -> listing: { price: 5, itemId, item: { weight: 10, userId, user: { name: "Bob } } }

Comment: listing, item and user are three separate collections, and inside listing i only store itemId, and inside item, I only store userId

Comment: Okay, I figured it out, wow thanks a lot man! This increased the performance of my app soooo much! and can get the SAME exact data!

Answer (score 1):

```
  const populate = (context) => {

  const stringList = [
    'vehicleId',
    'userId',
    'locationId',
  ];

  context.params.query['$populate'] = {
    path: `${stringList.join(' ')}`,
    populate: [
      {
        path: 'modelId',
        model: 'models',
        populate: {
          path: 'makeId',
          model: 'makes',
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'userId',
        model: 'users',
      },
    ],
  };

  return context;
};
```

Based on previous answer managed to do a research and ended up writing the following hook as the solution, for nested populate in FeathersJs